# Command to change numeric point from comma to dot

Tags: windows, command-line, keyboard

On the numeric keyboard, the key between the <kbd>0</kbd> and the <kbd>Enter</kbd> is the <kbd>. (Del)</kbd> key. When I use this key (in notepad, windows explorer, MS Word, ...) it gives me a comma instead of a point (full stop).

I know how to change this using the windows control panel, however I would love a commandline way to achieve this, so I can put this in my Autoexec.bat (changes in control panel are reverted each boot).

Does anyone know a **commandline option**, a setting, a small application (portable and with a commandline option) that does this?

Comment: You could simply create a new keyboard layout and install that. It's what I did. Works great.

Comment: The settings in your Regional and Language Option Control Panel (or version equivalent) may be for the wrong locale. Regardless you can change them there.